# fullCalendar('getView').visStart return undefined

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the start, end date of `fullCalendar`. If I use the the fullcalendar.min.js version the value is read correctly but If I import the normal version `fullcalendar.js` this code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').visStart,
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').visEnd;
```

return me undefined. Someone had the same problem? Maybe with the normal version of `fullcalendar` change something? I don't know.
Anyway in the `min version` all working well but I need to use the normal version for import some class.
This is a preview:

**min version (all working well):**

[image]

**full version (bug)**

[image]

Also the CSS are broken.

Comment: Are you sure the min and full versions are targeting the same FullCalendar version?
Also in FC 2.0, `.visStart` and `.visEnd` are deprecated and replaced by `.end` and `.start` (doc: http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/)

Comment: So something like this $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start ?

Comment: If you're using FC 2, yes. The object returned by `.start` is a Moment (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/)

Comment: Ok seems working thank you. Could you help me on this link problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236010/fullcalendar-doesnt-display-certain-date/33236114#33236114